# Checking if alphabetic string is a palindrome in C++

Tags: c++

I've attempted to write a code that checks whether or not a string is a palindrome. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool pal(string str)//This block of code checks if input string is a palindrome
{
bool valid;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    if (str[-i] == str[i])
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        valid = false;
    }
}
return valid;
}

int main()
{
string s;
cin >> s;

if (!pal(s))
{
    cout << "NO" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "YES" << endl;
}
return 0;
    }
```

Currently I am getting "Debug Assertion Fail" error.

Comment: str[-i] doesn't work in C++.. I guess you borrowed it from Python? You would need to do str[str.size()  - 1- i]

Comment: When `i` becomes 1 what is `str[-i]`?

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ palindrome alphabet".

Comment: Note that you reset `valid` every iteration, even if it's already `false`. Your loop is meaningless as you only know if the last compare was valid or not. You should discontinue the loop once you've found a mismatch.

Comment: @AlexG - yr code still fails if i = 5 for example, also str[-i] is fine as long as i >= 0

Comment: @pm100 Not sure where that 5 comes from ? If str.size() == 5, then you would get 5 - 1 - 4 = 0. ?

Comment: @pm100 AlexG is assuming that `i` is always less than `str.size()` since it's guarded against by the loop condition. If `i` were `5` then `str.size()` would be at least 6.

Comment: @pm100 How is `str[-i]` fine for all `i >= 0`?  If `i` is `3` then you get `str[-3]` which is *not fine*

Comment: @NAthanOliver my bad - I mean I <= 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str[-i] == str[i]
```

is a problem since negative indices are not valid indices in C++.

You need to change the strategy a little bit.

```
bool pal(string str)
{
   int i = 0;
   int j = str.length() - 1;

   for ( ; i < j; ++i, --j)
   {
      if (str[i] != str[j])
      {
         // No need for any more checks.
         return false;
      }
   }

   // If we come here, the string is a palindrome.    
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work as well. The second before I saw it, I manage to work out what was wrong.

Comment: if (str[str.size()-1-i] == str[i]). That the line I have now but thanks anyways

Comment: _negative indices are not valid indices in C++_ Technically, they are. But not the way the OP wants. Example: http://ideone.com/5gWNMK

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I realize that. I don't want to confuse the OP's current issue with the finer aspects of accessing arrays using negative indices.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Provides us with an inbuilt function reverse() which can be used to reverse the Input string and compare it with un reversed string and print the output. The code goes as follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str; 
    cin>> str;
    
    string rev;
    rev = str;

    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());  // string reverse operation
    
    if(rev == str){
        cout<<"YES"<<endl; // Prints "Yes" if string is palindrome
    }else{
        cout<<"NO"<<endl; // Prints "No" if string is not palindrome
    }

    return 0;
}
```